# Как сделать конструктор по умолчанию с параметрами

Tags: c++, функции, классы, конструктор

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();  

private:
    int x;
};

MyClass :: MyClass() : x(10)  
{
}

int main()
{
    MyClass first;  
}
```

Вот я реализовал класс с конструктором по умолчанию, но как теперь это превратить в конструктор по умолчанию с параметрами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"конструктор по умолчанию с параметрами" — это что-то типа твердой воды.

Но можно разрешить "конструктору с параметром" работать конструктором по умолчанию, если его можно вызывать без аргументов — а это можно, сделав аргумент аргументом со значением по умолчанию.

```
MyClass :: MyClass(int value = 10) : x(value)  
{
}
```